# ArangoDB query support

Tags: database, sorting, arangodb, aql, collect

I am looking for someone who can modify this ArangoDB query so that the results are presented in the correct alphabetical order.

In the image you can see that I searched for "stat". In the results, for example, Stat5 is above stat4. That is not good.

```
FOR p in k2p_product_as SEARCH 
  STARTS_WITH(p.searchNames, @search) OR STARTS_WITH(p.basic.name,@search) 
  FILTER p.basic['Active yes/no'] == 'Y' 
  COLLECT score=(0-TFIDF(p)), 
          name = p.basic.name, 
          description = p.basic.description, 
          clone = p.basic.Clone,
          reactivity = p.basic.Reactivity, 
          host = p.basic.Host, 
          applications = p.basic.Applications, 
          conjugate = p.basic.Conjugate, 
          source = p.basic.Source, 
          productCategoryLabNed = p.basic['Product category LabNed'], 
          image1 = p.basic.picture, 
          image2 = p.basic.price, 
          stamnummer = p.basic.Stamnummer 
  INTO sizesPrices = CONCAT(p.basic.Size, "", p.basic["Price LabNed"], "", p.basic.vat) 
  LIMIT 0, 10 
  RETURN {
      name: name,
      description: description,
      clone: clone,
      reactivity: reactivity,
      host: host,
      applications: applications,
      conjugate: conjugate,
      source: source,
      'Product category LabNed': productCategoryLabNed,
      images: { image1: image1, image2: image2 },
      stamnummer: stamnummer,
      sizesPrices: sizesPrices
  }
```

Comment: You refer to an image, but there isn't one in your post? Can you share the current query result, the desired query result and the View definition? There is no `SORT` operation, so an unordered result is actually to be expected.

Comment: Try lowercasing the value you want to sort by?